Why the associated graded universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra is Poisson?
Let $L$ be a Lie algebra and $U(L)$ be its universal enveloping algebra. How the associated graded algebra $grU(L)$ of the universal enveloping algebra $U(L)$ can be a Poisson algebra? How the Poisson bracket is defined? 0
I found that this file about relation between associative algebra and Poisson algebras.

$[XY, Z] = XYZ - ZXY = XYZ - XZY + XZY - ZXY = X[Y, Z] + [X, Z]Y$

the Poisson bracket is defined in Example 2.5 of the file you linked.
